# react native Animated.spring doesn't work smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'am using react native animated API to make a smooth transition from left to right position.
this is my initial state

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isDrawerOpened: false,
            left: new Animated.Value(-100)
        };
        this.setDrawer = this.setDrawer.bind(this);
    }
```

its still working fine when componentDidMount has called

```
componentDidMount() {
        Animated.spring(this.state.left, {toValue: 200}).start();
    }
```

But when i'am using event to change the state (also starting animation). The transition become rough (not smooth).
This is my event code

```
setDrawer() {
        this.setState({
            isDrawerOpened: !this.state.isDrawerOpened
        });

        if (this.state.isDrawerOpened) {
            this.setState({
                left: new Animated.Value(200)
            });
            Animated.spring(this.state.left, {toValue: -100, speed: 1000}).start();
        } else {
            this.setState({
                left: new Animated.Value(-100)
            });
            Animated.spring(this.state.left, {toValue: 200, speed: 1000}).start();
        }
    }
```

can anyone solve this :( , sorry for my bad english

Comment: Make sure that your app is not in Remote debugg mode, if it is your app will be way slower. Also, try testing it in release, your app should be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Try going for `useNativeDriver: true`. Your animations are now run in the JS thread and might be blocked by other stuff going on in your JS code. This will move animations to the UI thread.

See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#using-the-native-driver) for reference.